# Home made bottom bracket plastic sleeve

Tags: bottom-bracket, preventative-maintenance, diy

I want to make a plastic sleeve from a water bottle, for a classic cup and cone bottom bracket, to protect against moisture and impurities that may run down the seat tube.

How do I know the proper size I need to cut it to?
Is there a better material I can use, rather than a plastic bottle?

Comment: The shell does have a drain hole.

Comment: Its a good idea - my only answer would be "guesstimate"   Another alternative would be to dump the old cup and cone, and fit a sealed cartridge bearing which are much more water resistant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be simple enough to measure the B.B. shell width minus the width of the two cups to get a tailored fit. You can cut the circumference to fit while you work, but shell diameter is probably approx 34-35 mm.

But should you? At the moment any moisture etc running down the seat tube is pointing at the drain hole, perfect. If there is plastic in the way, moisture will be diverted, possibly towards the bearings you want to protect. Cartridge B.B.s have other seals to mitigate this.

If the B.B. is more precious to you than the cost of a replacement, consider removing it for safe keeping and using a sacrificial replacement, cartridge B.B. anyway.

Comment: You are right, the plastic will block the drain hole. The water bottle has a narrower portion in the middle, a curved shape; I was thinking to cut it such that the narrower portion forms a passage (from seat tube to drain hole) in the middle of the BB shell. Anyway, I'll order a cartridge BB online and cross my threads that the fingers will match. I also need to order a BB tool; hope that will match too. Shops in my country offer so little technical details about the products...

Answer (score 1):

Since the only opening through which debris can get into bottom bracket is the seat post (provided it is open from the top), **yes, there is a better material than a plastic bottle**. Simply stick a wine cork into the seat post blocking the opening. Not only you stop the debris from getting into the bottom bracket, you also stop them from getting into seat post and seat tube.

You can also place a so-called **micro adjust seat post**, which is closed from the top (picture only for illustration):

[image]

Comment: Someone voted this down. It would be better to provide an argument why this is not a good idea. I don't think it is unreasonable.

Comment: Quite often do I feel pity for providing a "think-outside-of-the-box" solution and being down-voted for "not providing a direct answer". Got used to it, though.

Comment: Thank you for your "think-outside-the-BB-shell" answer! I think I'll do what you suggest. But it will block air flow through the tube and BB shell. Is air flow important?